# I'm trying to use KernetTestKase in my unit tests, but I get a "not found" error

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, testing

I'm trying to follow some examples of using KernetTestCase for a Symfony 2 test that touches the DB.

I get this error:

`Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase' not found in...`

In my test files I have:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
```

and

```
class AcmeContestTest extends KernelTestCase
```

However I still get the error above when running tests...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that Symfony version 2.3 which I'm using doesn't have KernelTestCase extracted out of WebTestCase as Symfony version 2.5 has...

for reference check out: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test